# Convert or prefix numbers to British pounds £ in R

Tags: r, tidyr

The scales packages allows for numbers to be prefixed with $ for business reports, example:

`scales::dollar(mtcars$mpg)`

Is there a way to do similar for British pounds?

Comment: You want `scales::dollar(mtcars$mpg, prefix = "£")`.

Comment: This is implemented in this gist: https://gist.github.com/annoporci/542fd18fc0551f0706da But it looks like SamR has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @SamR for the answer:

```
scales::dollar(mtcars$mpg, prefix = "£")
```